# Passing from string to unsigned short

Tags: c, string, unsigned

I have 2 variables. One should be of type `unsigned short array[10]` (I am asked to do this), and the other will be an input from `scanf` that is convenient to be string.
I am passing the values one by one, from the string to the unsigned short with a for loop.
The programs works ok but I am getting warning messages.
`"Warning passing argument of strcmp from incobatible pointer type"`
and `"expected const char * but argument is of type short unsigned int"`.
I can't seem to find how to pass from a string to unsigned short without warnings.
A short version of my program is here so that you have a clearer view.

Warnings are at lines 28,43.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i, j, numberofseats;
char phone[11];
char *p;
unsigned short tempphone[10];
typedef struct
{
  char fullname[40];
  unsigned short phonenr[10];
  unsigned int seatnr;
} PASSENGERS;

int main()
{
  PASSENGERS passenger[53];
  printf("Enter Passenger's Phone Nr:");
  scanf("%s", phone);
  i = 0;
  for (p = phone; *p != '\0'; p++)
  {
    (tempphone[i]) = *p - '0';
    i++;
  }
  for (j = 0; j < numberofseats; j++)
  {
    if (strcmp(tempphone, passenger[j].phonenr) == 0)
      printf("Passenger %s has Seat Nr %u already Booked", passenger[j].fullname, passenger[j].seatnr);
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to store somewhere how many of the digits in `tempphone` are actually used. For the moment, you seem to be assuming **all**, but you only initialize the first `strlen(phone)` elements. Also, you cannot use `strcmp` to compare arrays of integers.

Comment: @tofro: "*you want to store somewhere how many of the digits*" The OP probably will learn this the moment the comparison actually  *works* ... ;-)

Comment: The program works fine.. By changing a line -> memcmp(tempphone,passenger[j].phonenr,sizeof(tempphone))==0) both of the warnings seem to go away..

Comment: Is this in a Windows environment with a unicode project?  It might be the reason why you have been asked to do it.  If it is, use the unicode routines like tcslen and tcscmp in place of strlen and strcmp.

Comment: Yes and yes, it was window with unicode.. Will also check on this! Thanks everyone! For now i am leaving it with memcmp

Answer (score 1):

You can use memcmp or casting to char* and use strcmp.
Keep in mind that memcmp requires the size of memory that will be compared as third parameter.

You can use memcmp like this,

```
memcmp(tempphone, passenger[j].phonenr, sizeof(tempphone));
```

However, it can result in wrong comparison if the size of the compared phone numbers are not the same and if one ends with the number 0.
Think about the case tempphone is 12345 and passenger[j].phonenr is 1234500000.
memcmp may judge the phone numbers are the same if you don't forget to initiate varibables to 0. You need another variable to keep the length of the phone number, of course, it doesn't matter if the phone numbers are fixed always.

I would keep phone numbers in array of chars instead of array of shorts and use strcmp. Phone numbers are numbers but they are not the objects of mathmatical operations like add or divide. They contains information similar to names.

Comment: Thank you also so much for the answer. Unfortunately i was asked to do so, so i am just working with it as it is..Also i have initialised all the values to 0 in another part of my full program for the phone number.. So maybe it is better to use tcslen or tcscmp that someone else proposed before?

Comment: "*casting to char\* and use strcmp*" is a bad idea as comparison stops with the 1st `0` found.

Comment: @alk, You're right. Casting just suppresses the warning message. The problem remains unsolved.

Comment: so instead of just using strings anywhere.. can i compare these 2 unsigned shorts correctly? Is memcmp a better option?

Comment: @bakson1, I would add a new variable to keep the length of phone number if you can't consider initiating array of shorts to the value that can't be a phone number such as -1. You need to compare the length of the phone numbers also if they're not the same in lengh.

Comment: Ok, will do this also an a variable for length! Thank you everyone for your solutions!